# Mysql all deadlock logs

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I can see the latest deadlock log with the command '`show engine innodb status;`'.
But now I want to see last two or three or more times deadlock log, how to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/87350

Have a look at this, you need to enable innodb_print_all_deadlocks